# error: expected value token when calling the GEP instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm playing with LLVM and have started with simple Hello World. Here's the code that I'm trying to run:

**test.s**:

```
; Declare the string constant as a global constant.                  
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"Hello world!\00"   

; External declaration of the puts function                          
declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) nounwind                            

; Definition of main function                                        
define i32 @main() {   ; i32()*                                      
  ; Convert [13 x i8]* to i8 *...                                    
  %cast210 = getelementptr [13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0 

  ; Call putr function to write out the string to stdout.
  call i32 @puts(i8* %cast210)
  ret i32 0
}
```

I took it from here                                                                  : http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#id610. When I run it I get the following error:

```
$lli test.s
lli: test.s:10:37: error: expected value token
 %cast210 = getelementptr [13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0
                                   ^
```

It's a bit confusing when code from official LLVM website fails. However, it can be fixed by modifying the problematic line as follows:

**test_fixed.s**:

```
; Declare the string constant as a global constant.                  
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"Hello world!\00"   

; External declaration of the puts function                          
declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) nounwind                            

; Definition of main function                                        
define i32 @main() {   ; i32()*                                      
  ; Convert [13 x i8]* to i8 *...                                    
  %cast210 = getelementptr [13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0 

  ; Call putr function to write out the string to stdout.
  call i32 @puts(i8* %cast210)
  ret i32 0
}
```

My question is: what is going on here? When I check the documentation for getelementptr: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#id937, I get the impression that **test.s** is indeed correct. Yet it doesn't work. Please help.

Some context info:

```
    $ lli -version
    LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
      LLVM version 3.3
      Optimized build.
      Built Jun 18 2013 (05:58:10).
      Default target: x86_64-pld-linux-gnu
      Host CPU: bdver1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a problem about the version mismatch between your `lli` and the official LLVM docs. The official LLVM docs is for the latest developing version of LLVM, `3.7`.

The LLVM IR code in your question was update on `Mar 4 2015`. according to [this link](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/af9251f66b0459bc0e79ae5c200f8bfcdb4a28f8#diff-8d461e7a9b63fa0e76f269617dc1e067), after `getelementptr` instruction format was updated.

However, your version of lli is `3.3`, which is released on `Jun 18 2013`.

Please update your llvm toolchain to the latest version, and try it again.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense, thank you! I'm new to LLVM and not always sure where to look for answers. This is very helpful!

Comment: @banach-space: hey, I am also getting the same error. I am using llvm3.8.1 to generate .ll file and I am using that .ll file to pass to my program which was earlier on llvm3.6. My program which takes input from this .ll file compiles with llvm3.8.1 successfully. So I thought there is no problem. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.